# Is there a way to override the return URL for a visualforce apex:detail component?

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page embedded in another page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
<html>
  <head>
      <base target="_top"></base>
  </head>
  <body>
     <apex:detail subject="{!Lead.My_Custom_Object__c}" inlineEdit="true" relatedList="true" title="false" />
  </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The base element is a rarely used piece of html which is useful in iframes for setting links to affect the parent frame instead of the embedded frame.

When people click on a link such as editing a property I want the retURL to be the parent page.

Is there a way to set the retURL in an apex:detail component?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `<apex:detail>` does not have that kind of facility.

You can use `<apex:pageBlockTable>` to render data and for navigation purpose.